# Angular validate directive with input field for unique value within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an html page with question and ability to add multiple options with Option and code and with ability to add or remove an option.

I need to validate the option codes for each code to be unique within the form

I wanted to validate code in the same directive. I am confused on how to validate this kind of fields where my directive has ng-repeat

Here's the link for [Plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqFuIl?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.question = { question: 'what is your name',
     options: [{option:'Red', code: '1'}, {option:'Blue', code: '2'},
     {option:'Green', code: '3'},{option:'Black', code: '4'}]};
});

app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

                function Option() {
                    this.option = '';
                    this.code = '';
                }

                scope.addOption = function(index) {
                    var existingOption = scope.question.options;
                    if (existingOption && existingOption.length) {
                        var newOption = new Option(index + 1);
                        scope.question.options.splice(index + 1, 0, newOption);
                    }
                }

                scope.removeOption = function (index) {
                    if (index > -1) {
                        scope.question.options.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                question: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'question.html'
        };
});
```

Comment: Do you want unique code on add option?  why do have add button next to every input? can it be just one at the last input so that when you add new option it only be after the last one?

Comment: I change your [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojGlUf?p=preview) but not sure if this what you want.